# How can I build a 'dependency tree diagram' from my .NET solution

Tags: .net, reflection, dependencies

I can get easily see what projects and dlls a single project references from within a Visual Studio .NET project.

Is there any application or use of reflection that can build me a full dependency tree that I can use to plot a graphical chart of dependencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to NDepend, you can also try this addin for [Reflector](http://www.codeplex.com/reflectoraddins/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Graph&referringTitle=Home) for showing assembly dependency graph.

Answer (score 10):

NDepend comes with an interactive dependency graph coupled with a dependency matrix. You can [download and use the free trial edition](http://www.ndepend.com/NDependDownload.aspx) of NDepend for a while.

[More on NDepend Dependency Graph](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_VS_Arch.aspx)
[image]

[More on NDepend Dependency Matrix](http://www.ndepend.com/Doc_Matrix.aspx):
[image]

*Disclaimer: I am part of the tool team*

Answer (score 8):

I needed something similar, but didn't want to pay for (or install) a tool to do it. I [created a quick PowerShell script that goes through the project references](https://blog.dantup.com/2012/05/free-dependency-graph-generation-using-powershell-and-yuml/) and spits them out in a [yuml.me](https://yuml.me/) friendly-format instead:

```
Function Get-ProjectReferences ($rootFolder)
{
    $projectFiles = Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Filter *.csproj -Recurse
    $ns = @{ defaultNamespace = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" }

    $projectFiles | ForEach-Object {
        $projectFile = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
        $projectName = $_ | Select-Object -ExpandProperty BaseName
        $projectXml = [xml](Get-Content $projectFile)
        
        $projectReferences = $projectXml | Select-Xml '//defaultNamespace:ProjectReference/defaultNamespace:Name' -Namespace $ns | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty "#text"
        
        $projectReferences | ForEach-Object {
            "[" + $projectName + "] -> [" + $_ + "]"
        }
    }
}

Get-ProjectReferences "C:\Users\DanTup\Documents\MyProject" | Out-File "C:\Users\DanTup\Documents\MyProject\References.txt"
```

[image: Sample Graph]
<sub>(source: [yuml.me](https://yuml.me/4f30e632))</sub>

Comment: +1 for providing the quickest path to a solution. In under two minutes I fired up PowerShell, ran your script, pasted the output into yuml.me and generated a graph. Very nice!  BTW, the code on your linked blog post produces slightly cleaner output than your abbreviated version here--this one throws in `"[project] -> []"` for projects lacking references. (It appears that yuml generates the same graph either way, though.)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dependency graph of projects and assemblies in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate by using Architecture Explorer to browse your solution, select projects and the relationships that you want to visualize, and then create a dependency graph from your selection.

For more info, see the following topics:

**How to: Generate Graph Documents from Code**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409453%28VS.100%29.aspx#SeeSpecificSource

**How to: Find Code Using Architecture Explorer**: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409431%28VS.100%29.aspx

**RC download**: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=457bab91-5eb2-4b36-b0f4-d6f34683c62a.

**Visual Studio 2010 Architectural Discovery & Modeling Tools** forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsarch/threads

Answer (score 0):

[Structure101](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/products/structure101/index.php) can do that. You can browse a model by assembly and/or namespace, and clicking on any dependency at any level give you all the code-level references that cause the dependency. The .NET version is in beta, but it's been available for other languages for years, so it's very mature. Here's an example screen shot. 
[alt text http://www.headwaysoftware.com/images/assemblies.jpg](http://www.headwaysoftware.com/images/assemblies.jpg)

Comment: The link is dead.