# How can I find out why an assembly is required in ASP.Net MVC4 project?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to deploy my ASP.Net MVC4 application to Azure but it is crashing during deployment. Apparently this is because something is requesting assembly *'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'* . This all works perfectly locally and is a nightmare to debug on Azure as deployment takes 25-30 minutes for me.

I had thought I had configured CLR to not require MVC3 even if something wanted it by using:

```
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
```

If I look at the ObjectBrowser nothing seems to be requiring MVC3. What is the best way to figure out what is requesting it? I have various Nuget packages in the project. I guess one of them is requesting MVC3? Is there anyway to see a list of all dependencies etc?

I get:

> CLR exception type: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException
>   "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information."
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Critical: 201 : ModLoad:
>   000007fc`906a0000 000007fc`907a9000
>   D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\diasymreader.dll Role
>   entrypoint could not be created: System.TypeLoadException: Unable to
>   load the role entry point due to the following exceptions:
>   -- System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
>   'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> ---> System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information.    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes()    at
>   System.Reflection.Assembly.GetTypes()    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly
>   entryPointAssembly)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.GetRoleEntryPoint(Assembly
>   entryPointAssembly)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.CreateRoleEntryPoint(RoleType
>   roleTypeEnum)    at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.RoleEnvironment.InitializeRoleInternal(RoleType
>   roleTypeEnum) ModLoad: 000007fc`a2f00000 000007fc`a2f96000
>   D:\Windows\SYSTEM32\clbcatq.dll ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess+0xa:
>   000007fc`a2fa2eaa c3              ret

and

> ```
>   Exception object: 00000000017e0070 Exception type:   System.TypeLoadException Message:          Unable to load the role
> ```
>
> entry point due to the following exceptions:
>   -- System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040) File name:
>   'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> InnerException:   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException, Use
>   !PrintException 00000000017dcf08 to see more. StackTrace (generated):
>    StackTraceString:  HResult: 80131522

Comment: As an aside - you should really look at using Azure Websites with Git deployment via BitBucket or TFS deployment - I had the same nightmare deployment time - takes under a minute if you use Websites: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/publishing-with-git/

Comment: Yeah I was considering web sites rather than web roles. However the main issue is our comms is what is causing the delay. We are getting new high speed comms in next few weeks so should improve things. Certainly looking more at the idea of continual deployment etc and hopefully get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reflector to load the Nuget packages and look at their dependencies. Should be fairly easy to spot whether one is dependent upon MVC3. Your assembly binding looks fine though. Do you have multiple projects in your solution? Could one of those be taking a dependency on a Nuget package that depends on MVC3?

This post may help: [How can I build a 'dependency tree diagram' from my .NET solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80287/how-can-i-build-a-dependency-tree-diagram-from-my-net-solution)

Comment: Yeah multiple projects. However it appears to be the web project. If I remove it and replace with a clean MVC4 project which references my domain and infrastructure projects it deploys perfectly.

Comment: Might it be worth registering for Websites quickly so that you can get this issue fixed with a shorter deployment time? You can always bin the account afterwards. You may have to go through and remove each Nuget package one at a time until you find the culprit. It'll be far less painful with websites!

Comment: Might be an idea, trying that now. NDepend shows 10 things require MVC. However nothing seems to suggest that it is MVC3 that is required. This is an area that is all pretty new to me. Should my bindingRedirect prevent the application demanding a specific version of MVC?

Comment: That's the idea. If a dependency relies on MVC3 and your project is using MVC4, the binding redirect should specifically stop the error that you're seeing. The binding redirect in my project looks slightly different but I'd be surprised if this fixed the issue. Try changing yours to `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />`

Comment: Yeah I had that originally and then tried changing to what I had. Thanks